# Array From API Response Doesn't Parse As Array When Using find or includes(Cypress, Node, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I created an array from a http response, and am attempting to iterate against an object list to create a second array of keys where the keys value is found in my http response array.  But I noticed for some reason using `find` or `includes`, the if statement never evaluates to true.  But if I replace my http array with an array of the exact same contents, it evaluates to true.

```
for (const property in partners) {
    cy.log('PARTNER SKU LIST', partnerSkuList);
    if (partnerSkuList.find((elem) => elem === partners[property])) {
      cy.log('TRUE');
      partnerNames.push(property);
    }
  }
  cy.log('NAMES LIST', partnerNames);
```

Log output:

```
PARTNER SKU LIST, [3]
NAMES LIST, []
```

Defining variable as array with same value:

```
for (const property in partners) {
    partnerSkuList = [3];
    if (partnerSkuList.find((elem) => elem === partners[property])) {
      cy.log('TRUE');
      partnerNames.push(property);
    }
  }
  cy.log('NAMES LIST', partnerNames);
```

Log output:

```
TRUE
NAMES LIST, [abc]
```

UPDATE:
Did some checking and my array is empty:

```
Given('the principal catalog identifier setting is set to partner_sku', () => {
  // Get a list of item checkin methods for all partners

  const partnerSkuList = [];
  const partnerNames = [];

  function partnerSettingsRequest(code, response) {
    cy.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: Cypress.env('adminApiUrl'),
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-company-app-name': 'admin:tests-ui',
      },
      body: {
        query:
          `query getSettingsByCode($code: String!) {
          configurationByCode(code: $code) {
            data {
              value
              partnerId
            }
          }
        }`,
        variables: {
          code,
        },
      },
    }).then(response);
  }

  const partnerSkuResponse = (res) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < res.body.data.configurationByCode.length; i += 1) {
      if (res.body.data.configurationByCode[i].data.value !== null
        && res.body.data.configurationByCode[i].data.partnerId !== null
        && res.body.data.configurationByCode[i].data.value.includes('partner_sku')
        && Object.values(partners).includes(res.body.data.configurationByCode[i].data.partnerId)) {
        partnerSkuList.push(res.body.data.configurationByCode[i].data.partnerId);
      }
    }
    return partnerSkuList;
  };

  partnerSettingsRequest('checkin_cid1', partnerSkuResponse);

  for (const property in partners) {

    if (partnerSkuList.length === 0) {
      cy.log('ARRAY EMPTY');
    }

    cy.log('PARTNER SKU LIST', partnerSkuList);
    if (partnerSkuList.includes(partners[property])) {
      cy.log('ADDING PROPERTY');
      partnerNames.push(property);
    }
  }

  cy.log('NAMES LIST', partnerNames);
```

Comment: Hi anutter - Your question is about a data structure that you have trouble with but you didn't include the data. I doubt `Array.prototype.find()` has a bug. You test with known good and it works flawlessly. So that leaves one thing - the data. Please provide the data structure you are having difficulty with. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, especially if you're new to a language or framework (you said "lack of knowledge"), your problem probably isn't a bug in the extensively used language/framework, but your code.

Comment: Which is why I posted on here, hoping someone can explain to me what kind of a bit difference would cause two seemingly equal arrays to yield two different results?

Comment: The data structure you provided is invalid and will not parse. You are not helping us to help you. That data structure is either raw JSON or has been double escaped and is not usable in that form. Please try to do your part by providing code that will at least parse correctly. We can't diagnose a problem without at least some sort of parsable data.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Added the full code, seems I am doing something wrong regarding the async nature of JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an async issue, just needed to wrap my code in a promise.  So added an extra arg to my request function `filter`, theennn(pun intended):

```
}).then(response).then(filter);
```

```
const getPartnerNames = () => {
    for (const property in partners) {
      cy.log('PARTNER SKU LIST', partnerSkuList);
      if (partnerSkuList.includes(partners[property])) {
        cy.log('ADDING PROPERTY');
        partnerNames.push(property);
      }
    }
  };
```

`partnerSettingsRequest('checkin_cid1', partnerSkuResponse, getPartnerNames);`